# Pass row.item.attribute value to a modal with Bootstrap Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-modal

I have a table where in the last column there is a button that pressing it pops-up a modal with some information and actions to do.
To this modal I want to pass a value from the table (from a specific cell of each row) but the modal shows always  the cell value from the last row of the table (it is like it considers the whole table as one row).
To do some test I wrote the attribute to be appeared on the button title ,and so far it works well (to each button it appears the correct attribute of each row).
It seems that in the next level (inside the modal) there is a misunderstanding and whichever modal opens it presents always the cell value of the last row.
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECKyi.png)
[modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sg6dh.png)

```
 <b-table
                        sticky-header
                          selectable
                          select-mode="single"
                          selected-variant="success"
                          w-auto
                          show-empty
                          small
                          stacked="md"
                          id="eventdataTable"
                          striped
                          hover
                          responsive
                          :items="items"
                          :fields="event_columns"
                          :per-page="perPage"
                          :current-page="currentPage"
                          :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
                          :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc"
                          :sort-direction="sortDirection"
                          :filter="filter"
                          :filterIncludedFields="filterOn"
                          @filtered="onFiltered"
                        > 
                        <template v-slot:cell(nearby_venues)="row">  
                            <div>                     
                              <b-button
                                variant="info"
                                class="text-center"
                                size="sm"
                                @click="show1 = true"
                               v-b-modal="'modal1'"                       
                                >Nearby Venues  {{ row.item.api_id }}
                               </b-button>
                              <b-modal                         
                                id="modal1"
                                ok-variant="info"
                                v-model="show1"
                                size="sm"
                                title="Nearby Venues"
                              > {{ row.item.api_id }}  *This appears correct*                                           
                                  <p align="left">Choose Venues close to</p>
                                  <b-form-select
                                  v-model="userdata.eventApiId"
                                    class="mb-3"
                                  >
                                      <template slot="first">
                                      <option :value="row.item.api_id">
                                        {{ row.item.api_id }} *This appears wrong -the value of the column cell from the last row*
                                      </option>
                                    </template>
                                 
                                </b-form-select>
                                
                                  <label
                                    class="mr-sm-3"
                                    for="venue-category-selection"
                                  ></label>
                                  <b-form-select
                                    class="mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0"
                                    v-model="userdata.selectedVenueCategory"
                                    :options="venue_categories"
                                    value-field="id"
                                    text-field="name"
                                    id="venue-category-selection"
                                    size="sm"
                                  ></b-form-select>
                                
                                <hr width="300" align="left" />
                                <div>
                                  <p align="left">Distance</p>
                                  <label
                                    class="mr-sm-3"
                                    for="event-place-selection"
                                  ></label>
                                  <b-form-input
                                    v-model="userdata.distance"
                                    placeholder="distance"
                                    width="5px"
                                  ></b-form-input
                                  >km.

                                  <b-button
                                    size="sm"
                                    variant="success"
                                    @click="VenuesFromSelectedEvent"
                                    v-b-toggle.collapse-2
                                  >
                                    Click Here
                                  </b-button>
                                </div>
                              </b-modal>
                            </div>
                        </template>                     
                          </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that there is a loop in this component going through every row, rendering a new `b-modal` for each row. The problem is in this part of the code:

````
```
<b-form-select
      v-model="userdata.eventApiId"
      class="mb-3">
```
````

Each time a modal is rendered for a new row, it changes the `userdata.eventApiId` to the value for the current row. So the `userdata.eventApiId` will always end up being the `api_id` for the last row of the table.

One solution would be to change the code so that when the button is clicked, you change the `userdata.eventApiId` to the `row.item.api_id`.

I also wouldn't recommend putting the modal in the loop, as you would be creating a lot of hidden modals. I would just have one modal outside of the table that changes the value of userdata.

Comment: Problem solved :-) Thank you so much for your help and support!